# (0 _reactNavigationStack.createAppContainer) is not a function

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am getting the following error: (0 _reactNavigationStack.createAppContainer) is not a function. I got this error after installing react-native-gesture-handler and linking it.  However, I check the terminal and there are no error messages appearing.  The ios simulator is telling me that it is in App.JS, where I created the navigator, in the line where I have export deafult.  I was wondering if anyone can see something I may not be seeing.

This is how I have my navigator set up, which is in the App.js file.

```
import {
  createStackNavigator,
  createAppContainer
} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import SearchScreen from './src/screens/SearchScreen';

const navigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Search: SearchScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Search',
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      title: 'Buisness Search',
    },
  },
);

export default createAppContainer(navigator)
```

;

Answer (score 17):

If you are using React v4 and higher the code below should work

```
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
```

Answer (score 15):

This is because `createAppContainer` is not exported by `react-navigation-stack`

You can import it from `react-navigation`

```js
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
```

Comment: I originally did that, but I get the message createStackNavigator has been move to react-navigation-stack.

Comment: you should only take `createAppContainer` from `react-navigation` and `createStackNavigator` from `react-navigation-stack` !

Answer (score 3):

First install the dependencies :

```sh
run npm install react-navigation@^3.0.0 
run npm install react-native-gesture-handler
```

Then import it in your code :

```js
import { createStackNavigator} from "react-navigation-stack"
import { createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation'
```